Number disappears when textbox textmode=number
I have a textbox with textmode="number" in HTML:
<asp:TextBox  Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Blue" runat ="server" ID="txtProjectCost" format="0.###"
                                    min="0" TabIndex ="7" Wrap="False" TextMode ="Number"  >
</asp:TextBox>

When I set textbox text from code behind it shows decimal value, but it does not show in textbox. I tried combinations
 txtProjectCost.Text = Decimal.Parse(tb.Rows(0).Item(7))

I this also
txtProjectCost.Text = FormatNumber(CDbl(tb.Rows(0).Item(6)), 3)
but no number is displayed in textbox. I want number to be displayed in "..nnn.000" format, i.e., if no decimal number then padding. I want only numbers to be added in textbox.

Try below snippet. I tested it
bool isAValid = Decimal.TryParse(tb.Rows(0).Item(7), out a);

txtProjectCost.Text = a.ToString() ;
